# Read Certificate in Dynamics CRM custom workflows

Tags: c#, ssl, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

I've added certificate file in notes attachment of one of custom entity and I need to read that certificate in one of custom workflow. Below is my code snippet but it throws exception that **Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.SecurityException,mscrolib, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=natural, publicKeyToken=xxxxxxx' failed**

Below is the code snippet from custom workflows:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
byte[] certRawData = Convert.FromBase64String(notesAttachment.Entities[0].Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certRawData, Decrypt(certPass, "ABCXYZ", true));
ServiceSoapClient soapClient = new ServiceSoapClient(binding, endPoint);
soapClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
soapClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = cert;
```

Any idea what I am missing here to read the certificate properly? or what is the good way to read certificate in dynamics CRM workflows?